# How to capture everything until another capture group

Tags: regex

I have the following template :

```
1251 Left Random Text I want to fill  
It can go through multiple lines  
As you can see  
9841 Right Again we see a lot of random text with 3115 numbers  
And this also goes  
To multiple lines  
0121 Right    
5151 Right This one is just one line  
I was wrong  
9731 Left This one is just a line  
5123 NA Instruction 5151 was wrong  
4113 Right Instr 9841 was correct  
We checked
```

---

I want to have 3 groups:

```
1251  

Left  

Random Text I want to fill  
It can go through multiple lines  
As you can see
```

I'm using

```
(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(.*)
```

but it stops at the current line only (so I get only `Random Text I want to fill` in group 3, although I want including `As you can see`)
If I'm using Single line flag I get only 1 match for each group, group 3 almost being all

Here is live : https://regex101.com/r/W3x0mH/4

Comment: Logic : Number  followed by Right or Left and the 3rd group continues until you get number and Right or Left  ? Explain these Lines :  Line a)9841 Right Again we see a lot of Line b) random text with 3115 numbers
And this also goes
To multiple lines
Line c)0121 Right
Line d) 5151 Right This one is just one line

Comment: It can be Right or Left or something else @RizwanM.Tuman. What do you mean to explain ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a repeating group matching all the lines while asserting that the next line does not start wit 1+ digits followed by Left or Right:

```
(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d+)\s(\w+)\s` Match the first 2 groups
- `(`Third capturing group

  - `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
  - `(?:` Non capturing group
    `\r?\n(?!\d).*` Match newline, assert what is on the right is not a digit
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U4OKyn/1)

Comment: I'm not always sure is Left/Right, it can also be another word: NA as you can see in the example. Also, there may be others.

Comment: @Razvan Is the [updated pattern](https://regex101.com/r/0o2N10/2) working for you?

Comment: This is an expression I'd use, although the quantifier in `(?!\d+)` is redundant. Also, since we do not know the regex flavor, the `\r?`might be necessary before `\n` for those regex engines where `.` does not match carriage return symbols. Certainly, if `\R` construct is supported, it should be used instead of `\n`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, thank you for your comment!. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```
^(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(.*?)(?=\n\d|\z)
```

with DOTALL and MULTILINE modifiers.

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W3x0mH/7)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Line start
- `(\d+)`: Match and capture 1+ digits in group #1
- `\s`: match a whitespace
- `(\w+)`: Match and capture 1+ word characters in group #2
- `\s`: match a whitespace
- `(.*?)`: Match 0 or more of any character (non-greedy) provided next lookahead assertion is satiSfied
- `(?=\n\d|\z)`: Lookahead assertion to assert that we have a newline followed by a digit or there is end of input

---

**Faster Regex:**

If you are using this regex on a long string then you should also keep **overall performance** in mind as a regex with `DOTALL` modifier will tend to get slow on a large size text. For that I suggest using this regex that doesn't need DOTALL modifier:

```
^(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(.*(?:\n.*)*?)(?=\n\d|\z)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/W3x0mH/8)

On regex101 demo this regex takes just **`181` steps** as compared to first one that takes **`1300` steps**.

Answer (score 1):

For the third group, repeat any character while using negative lookahead for `^\d`, which would indicate the start of a new match:

```
(\d+)\s(\w+)\s((?:(?!^\d)[\s\S])*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/W3x0mH/5

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this regex:

```
^(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.*?)(?=^\d|\z)
```

1. `^(\d+)\s+` , `^\d+` Line begins with numbers followed by one or more whitespace character `\s+`
2. `(\w+)\s+` where `\w+` one or more characters (left,right,na or something else) followed by one or more whitespace `\w+`
3. `(.*?)` matches everything until it finds a line beginning with number or `\z` end of string.

I think it fits your requirement....

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/n1KHzy/1)